# Can't create transaction: failed to get random outputs to mix: failed to get random outs

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon

I'm using monero-wallet-gui (monero-gui-0.10.3.1-beta2). I'm connecting to remote node node.moneroworld.com : 18089

Network Status at bottom shows Connected.

I'm trying to send XMR to Binance exchange.

I tried sending upto 2.4 XMR and transactions are getting created for amounts less than 2.4. But when I enter anything more than 2.5, it gives me the following error: "Can't create transaction: failed to get random outputs to mix: failed to get random outs"

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're using too old a version, and won't be able to sync past where you are now.

Next, the reason for this message is that you're sending a lot of outputs, and nodes exposed to the public have an artificial limit to the number of outputs they will serve, as a crude defense against DoS. This limit is set to increase in next release.

So the solution is to send smaller amounts at a time, so the tx needs less outputs to meet the requested amount. You probably have lots of small outputs, likely from mining. You can think of it as having $100 in one cent coins. You have the money, but it takes work/time to use.

Comment: Thanks! Upgraded wallet and sending smaller transaction amounts.